# How to better build a database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

We have a DB on SQL, where we have a table (1) for users and a table (2) for user's saved information. Each piece of information is one line in table (2). So my question is the following - If we are intending to grow number of users to more than 1.000.000 and each user can have more than 10 piece of information, which of the following is a better way to build our DB:

a) Having 2 tables - 1 for users and 1 for information from all users, related to users with ID

b) Having a separate table for each user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Alternative a! (b is horrible.)

Comment: 100% a. Why would you want 1.000.000 tables for each user?

Comment: (b) is beyond horrible.  It can never scale.  MySQL can handle a million users with 100s of child rows if indexed properly.  You're guilty of premature optimization here.

Comment: Hi jarlh, thanks so much. Just having 1.000.000 user with 10 lines for each will mean 10.000.000 lines in DB. Won't it affect the speed, rather than having a separate table for each user's info?

Comment: Your design for table 2 is horrible. It is called an EAV table and it is a killer for performance. Do your job correctly and define the user attributes you need as separate columns in this table. If you need some flexibilty in the attributes add an EAV table after but 99% of the attributes you need should be definable up front and that will make you database work far better.  If you truly can't figure out what the attributes should be then a relational database is the wrong tool.

Comment: Got it, will go with option a then.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely it should be having a single table for the user is much better. Think from the DB prospective. You are thinking about the search time in a 1.000.000 row for a sorted ID. In the second case you have to search 1.000.000 table to get into a right table. So better go for option **A**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to agree that option A is the better of the two options presented.

That being said, I would personally break up the information for the users into more tables as well.  This would all be connected using foreign keys and will allow for more specific querying of the information.

SQL is not really horizontally scalable, so if you end up with users with less or more information than others, then you'll have NULL columns and this requires dealing with in various ways.

By using separate tables, you can still have all of the information contained, but not have to worry if one user has a home and cell phone number, while another only has a cell number.

If and when you do need to access a lot of the information at once, SQL is very good at dealing with this through joins and the like.

Option B is not bad, it just does not fit SQL.  I would work if the DB in question was document based instead of tables.  In that case, creating a single document for each user is a good idea, and likely preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Option C)
table for users with a unique UserID as Clustered Index (Primary Key)
table for Type of saved information with a unique InformationID as Clustered Index (Primary Key)
table for UserInformation with unique UserInformationID as Clustered Index (Primary Key), a column for UserID (nonclustered index, foreign key to user table) and a column for InformationID (nonclustered index, foreign key to Information table).  Have a "Value" or similar column to hold the data being save as it relates to the type of information.

Example:
Users Table

```
UserID UserName
1     | UserName1
2     | UserName2
```

Information Table

```
InfoID InfoName
1     | FavoriteColor
2     | FavoriteNumber
3     | Birthday
```

UserInformation Table

```
ID    UserID  InfoID  Value
1     | 1     | 1     | Blue
2     | 1     | 2     | 7
3     | 1     | 3     | '11/01/1999'
4     | 2     | 3     | '05/16/1960'
```

This method allows for you to save any combination of values for any user without recording any of the non-supplied user information.  It keeps the information table 'clean' because you won't need to keep adding columns for each new piece of information you wish to track.  Just add a new record to the Info table, and then record only the values submitted to the UserInformation table.